# Facebook Audience Network native crash with Android 10

Tags: android, crash, facebook-audience-network

I have crashes happening using latest version of Audience Network with almost all Pixel phones running Android 10. Here is the trace :

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000008246c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+160)
  #01  pc 00000000004ba0c4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2176)
  #02  pc 000000000000c634  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+604)
  #03  pc 00000000003781f0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1608)
  #04  pc 00000000003784a0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+180)
  #05  pc 00000000004ffc84  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DecodeJObject(_jobject*) const+780)
  #06  pc 00000000003c6228  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::GetArrayLength(_JNIEnv*, _jarray*)+580)
  #07  pc 0000000000038d10  /apex/com.android.conscrypt/lib64/libjavacrypto.so (evpUpdate(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jbyteArray*, int, int, char const*, int (*)(env_md_ctx_st*, void const*, unsigned long))+308)
  #08  pc 000000000013f350  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+144)
  #09  pc 00000000020007b4  /memfd:/jit-cache (com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLMessageDigestJDK.engineUpdate+116)
  #10  pc 00000000002609c0  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate.engineUpdate+64)
  #11  pc 00000000001bd6cc  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.security.MessageDigest.update+76)
  #12  pc 0000000002000f70  /memfd:/jit-cache (com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Nt.A01+416)
  #13  pc 000000000013663c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_osr_stub+60)
  #14  pc 00000000003380ac  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::jit::Jit::MaybeDoOnStackReplacement(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, unsigned int, int, art::JValue*)+1772)
  #15  pc 00000000005ad260  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpMaybeDoOnStackReplacement+212)
  #16  pc 0000000000135350  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpHelpers+240)
  #17  pc 00000000001a4fbe  [anon:dalvik-DEX (com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Nt.A01+66)
  #18  pc 00000000005a5154  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1160)
  #19  pc 0000000000130994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
  #20  pc 00000000001a509a  [anon:dalvik-DEX (com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Nt.A02+10)
  #21  pc 00000000002b4b04  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEbb.llvm.11452150525172173309+240)
  #22  pc 0000000000593744  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+944)
  #23  pc 000000000013f468  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88)
  #24  pc 00000000001365b8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568)
  #25  pc 0000000000145084  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+276)
  #26  pc 00000000002e3bc0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+384)
  #27  pc 00000000002deab8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+928)
  #28  pc 00000000005a4e3c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+368)
  #29  pc 0000000000130994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
  #30  pc 0000000000172ac4  [anon:dalvik-DEX (com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Jp.A02+104)
  #31  pc 00000000005a5154  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1160)
  #32  pc 0000000000130994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
  #33  pc 0000000000172b4c  [anon:dalvik-DEX (com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Jp.A03)
  #34  pc 00000000005a5154  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1160)
  #35  pc 0000000000130994  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20)
  #36  pc 00000000001728b8  [anon:dalvik-DEX (com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Jo.A00+16)
  #37  pc 00000000005a4934  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1192)
  #38  pc 0000000000130914  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20)
  #39  pc 0000000000172918  [anon:dalvik-DEX (com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.Jo.call)
  #40  pc 00000000002b4b04  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadERKNS_20CodeItemDataAccessorERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEbb.llvm.11452150525172173309+240)
  #41  pc 0000000000593744  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+944)
  #42  pc 000000000013f468  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88)
  #43  pc 0000000000298528  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run+200)
  #44  pc 00000000002019d4  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call+68)
  #45  pc 0000000000298528  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run+200)
  #46  pc 00000000002f9fd8  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker+984)
  #47  pc 00000000002f7640  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run+64)
  #48  pc 00000000001a50b8  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+72)
  #49  pc 0000000000136334  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #50  pc 0000000000145064  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+244)
  #51  pc 00000000004b1c58  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
  #52  pc 00000000004b2d28  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+416)
  #53  pc 00000000004f3290  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1172)
  #54  pc 00000000000e372c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
  #55  pc 0000000000084004  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

I'm using `implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.6.0'` and `new AdView(context, adUnit, BANNER_HEIGHT_50)` along with `AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(activity.getApplicationContext());` to initialize SDK first.

Does someone encounter the same issue and have a fix for it ?

Comment: only Android 10 - Pixel phones

Comment: I'm still seeing this crash with Facebook 5.8.0 :-(

Comment: facing the same issue here.any progress or updates? were u able to solve it?

Comment: Still hapens on latest versions (Facebook Audience Network 6.14.0 and Google Ads Mediation 6.14.0.0). Only on Android 10, but on various devices. Any new information from your side?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downgrading to 5.4.1 / crash have disappeared

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.4.1'
```

Comment: Hey, do you still use this old version or have you resolved it in other way?

Answer (score 0):

This is very bad of Facebook Developers involved in SDK development.

This issue is spiking even in sdk versions 6.0.0

Yesterday only they released 6.1.0. I'm not sure they resolved this issue. But their change log of 6.0.0 mention this

> Fixed net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED in Interstitials and Rewarded Video on Android 10+

here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/changelog-android#6_1_0

But is this is the reason for this Abort crash.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause bug in Android's InMemoryDexClassLoader https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150633385. Fixed in AN SDKs 6.1.0+

Comment: it seems i am still having it in 6.2.0